# Manage Order "Credit Memo" Error in Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, creditmemo, edit-order

I use Magento 2.2.1

I get this error after a customer places an order and i click on "Credit Memo" at

**Sales-> Orders-> view(or click on an order) -> Credit Memo**

```
 1 exception(s):
 Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Division by zero in /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/phoenix/module-cashondelivery/Model/Total/Creditmemo.php on line 88

 Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Division by zero in /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/phoenix/module-cashondelivery/Model/Total/Creditmemo.php on line 88
 #0 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/phoenix/module-cashondelivery/Model/Total/Creditmemo.php(88): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Division by zer...', '/home/139142.cl...', 88, Array)
 #1 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/phoenix/module-cashondelivery/Model/Total/Creditmemo.php(62): Phoenix\CashOnDelivery\Model\Total\Creditmemo->setCustomRefund(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo))
 #2 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Creditmemo.php(337): Phoenix\CashOnDelivery\Model\Total\Creditmemo->collect(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo))
#3 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/CreditmemoFactory.php(99): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo->collectTotals()
#4 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/CreditmemoLoader.php(211): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory->createByOrder(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor), Array)
#5 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/NewAction.php(63): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\CreditmemoLoader->load()
#6 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/NewAction/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\NewAction->execute()
#7 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\NewAction\Interceptor->execute()
#8 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(229):     Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\NewAction\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#11 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\NewAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\NewAction\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\NewAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Creditmemo/NewAction/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\NewAction\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#15 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\NewAction\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#18 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#20 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#22 /home/139142.cloudwaysapps.com/qvbzhkfrey/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#23 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I copied `Magento2-CashOnDelivery/Model/Total/Creditmemo.php`[Credit Memo Github](https://github.com/PHOENIX-MEDIA/Magento2-CashOnDelivery/blob/25009f385538cdd1adfcd79e00bdb2111ebdd64f/Model/Total/Creditmemo.php) to  my `/public_html/vendor/phoenix/module-cashondelivery/Model/Total/Creditmemo.php`. I got another error after that, so i copied `Magento2-CashOnDelivery/Helper/Data.php` from [Data.php](https://github.com/PHOENIX-MEDIA/Magento2-CashOnDelivery/blob/25009f385538cdd1adfcd79e00bdb2111ebdd64f/Helper/Data.php) to Magento2-CashOnDelivery/Helper/Data.php and everything works fine now.

I hope someone will find the answer useful.